# Replace certain occurrences of a characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I want to replace certain occurrences of a character in a string, not sure how to achieve it with regex.

```
originalString =  '=(IF(OR(L4=NULL,L4=""),0,L4)'
```

I want to replace it with letter M in such a way :

```
finalString = '=(IF(OR(M4=NULL,M4=""),0,M4)'
```

When using split or replace as shown below, even the L in the 'NULL' gets replaced.

```
finalString = originalString.split('L').join('M')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, you need to replace L each time it's followed by digit, right? `.replace(/L(?=\d)/gi, 'M')` seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to replace `M` with `L` when `M` is at the beginning of a word and followed by at least one digits. If so, you can use the `\b` ("word boundary") assertion and `\d` (a digit) around `M` to say which specific `M`s you want to replace. You can wrap the `\d` in a lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`) so it's not actually part of the match. To do it throughout the string, you want the "global" flag (`g`). So taking that all together: `/\bM(?=\d)/`

```js
const originalString =  '=(IF(OR(L4=NULL,L4=""),0,L4)';
const updated = originalString.replace(/\bM(?=\d)/g, "L");
console.log(updated);
```

If you also want to replace `m` with `L`, add the `i` (case insensitive) flag.